# Why is my Sub printing only 1 line at a time instead of 30?

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, text-files, streamreader

I'm currently writing a GUI for xmr-stak (www.xmrgui.com)
Having some trouble getting the output from the program and basically want to grab the last 30 lines from the output text file and append them to the RichTextBox if they don't already exist. Storing the text file in memory isn't a big issue because it will be deleted every 20 min or so...at least so I think. Maybe my function is taking up too much memory or time as it is.

My only requirement is that the Sub TimerOutput_tick can process each of the 30 last lines of text from the file to run a regex on each line and that the RichTextBox does not repeat old information.

Heres my code:

```
Private Function getlastlines(filename As String, numberOfLines As Integer) As Dictionary(Of Integer, String)
    Try
        Dim fs = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)
        Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(fs)
        Dim everything As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)
        Dim n As Integer = 1
        While reader.Peek > -1
            Dim line = reader.ReadLine()
            If everything.ContainsKey(n) Then
                everything(n) = line
                n += 1
            Else
                everything.Add(n, line)
                n += 1
            End If
        End While
        Dim results As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)
        Dim z As Integer = 1
        If n - numberOfLines > 0 Then
            For x As Integer = n - numberOfLines To n - 1
                'MsgBox(everything.Count - numberOfLines)
                If results.ContainsKey(z) Then
                    results(z) = everything(x)
                    z += 1
                Else
                    results.Add(z, everything(x))
                    z += 1
                End If
            Next

        End If

        Return results
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try

End Function
' GRABS XMR-STAK OUTPUT FROM ReadLastLinesFromFile AND RUNS A REGEX ON THE HASHRATE TO PROVIDE VALUES TO THE CHART
```

And here is the Sub that calls the previous function:

```
Private Sub timeroutput_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles timeroutput.Tick
    'Try
    Dim lateststring = getlastlines(xmroutput, 30)
    Try
        If lateststring IsNot rtlateststring Then
            Dim kvp As KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String)
            For Each kvp In lateststring
                If lateststring.ContainsKey(kvp.Key) Then


                    Dim line = kvp.Value
                    RichTextBox1.AppendText(line & vbCrLf)


                    If line.Contains("Totals") Then ' Should be "Totals"
                        'Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("\d+?.\d+")
                        Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("\d{1,5}\.\d{1,1}") ' match a double
                        Dim ret = regex.Match(line).Value

                        If ret <> "" Then
                            Dim iSpan As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(upseconds)
                            Label8.Text = "Uptime - Hours: " & iSpan.Hours & " Minutes: " & iSpan.Minutes & " Seconds: " & iSpan.Seconds & "               " & ret & " H/s"
                            NotifyIcon1.Text = "Uptime - Hours: " & iSpan.Hours & vbCrLf & " Minutes: " & iSpan.Minutes & vbCrLf & " Seconds: " & iSpan.Seconds & vbCrLf & ret & " H/s"
                        Else
                            Dim iSpan As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(upseconds)
                            NotifyIcon1.Text = "Uptime - Hours: " & iSpan.Hours & vbCrLf & " Minutes: " & iSpan.Minutes & vbCrLf & " Seconds: " & iSpan.Seconds & vbCrLf & "Initializing..."
                            Label8.Text = "Uptime - Hours: " & iSpan.Hours & " Minutes: " & iSpan.Minutes & " Seconds: " & iSpan.Seconds & "            Initializing..."
                            ret = "0.0"
                        End If
                        'Dim match As Match = regex.Match(lastline)
                        newhashrate = Convert.ToDouble(ret)
                    ElseIf line.Contains("NVIDIA") Then
                        Dim regexnv As Regex = New Regex("\d{1,5}\.\d{1,1}") ' match a double
                        Dim retnv = regexnv.Match(line).Value
                        newNVhashRate = Convert.ToDouble(retnv)
                        If firstNV = False Then
                            newser.Add(nvidiacard1)
                            nvidiacard1.Title = "NIVIDIA Hashrate(H/s)"
                            nvidiacard1.Values = nvidiavalues
                            nvidiavalues.add(0)
                            nvidiavalues.add(4)
                            nvidiavalues.add(2)
                            nvidiavalues.add(5)
                            firstNV = True
                        End If
                    ElseIf line.Contains("AMD") Then
                        Dim regexAMD As Regex = New Regex("\d{1,5}\.\d{1,1}") ' match a double
                        Dim retAMD = regexAMD.Match(line).Value
                        newAMDhashrate = Convert.ToDouble(retAMD)
                        If firstAMD = False Then
                            newser.Add(AMDCard1)
                            AMDCard1.Title = "AMD Hashrate(H/s)"
                            AMDCard1.Values = AMDValues
                            AMDValues.add(0)
                            AMDValues.add(4)
                            AMDValues.add(2)
                            AMDValues.add(5)
                            firstAMD = True
                        End If
                    End If
                    ' Now if a GPU exists, add a new lineseries for CPU
                    If firstAMD = True Or firstNV = True Then
                        If firstCPU = False Then
                            newser.Add(CPU1)
                            CPU1.Title = "CPU Hashrate(H/s)"
                            CPU1.Values = CPUValues
                            CPUValues.add(0)
                            CPUValues.add(4)
                            CPUValues.add(2)
                            CPUValues.add(5)
                            firstCPU = True
                        End If
                        newCPUhashrate = newhashrate - newNVhashRate - newAMDhashrate
                    End If
                    rtlateststring = lateststring
                End If
            Next
            RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = RichTextBox1.Text.Length
        End If
    Catch
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a much easier solution, running the code within one function and then loading the entire text file into the richtextbox. From there its much easier to read the last ten lines individually:

```
Private Sub timeroutput_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles timeroutput.Tick
    Try
        'Dim lateststring = getlastlines(xmroutput, 30)
        ' START NEW TEST
        Dim fs = File.Open(xmroutput, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)
        Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(fs)
        Dim wholefile = reader.ReadToEnd
        RichTextBox1.Text = wholefile
        RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = RichTextBox1.Text.Length
        For x As Integer = 1 To 10
            Dim line As String = RichTextBox1.Lines(RichTextBox1.Lines.Length - x)
            If line.Contains("Totals") Then ' Should be "Totals"
                'Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("\d+?.\d+")
                Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("\d{1,5}\.\d{1,1}") ' match a double
                Dim ret = regex.Match(line).Value

                If ret <> "" Then
                    Dim iSpan As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(upseconds)
                    Label8.Text = "Uptime - Hours: " & iSpan.Hours & " Minutes: " & iSpan.Minutes & " Seconds: " & iSpan.Seconds & "               " & ret & " H/s"
                    NotifyIcon1.Text = "Uptime - Hours: " & iSpan.Hours & vbCrLf & " Minutes: " & iSpan.Minutes & vbCrLf & " Seconds: " & iSpan.Seconds & vbCrLf & ret & " H/s"
                Else
                    Dim iSpan As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(upseconds)
                    NotifyIcon1.Text = "Uptime - Hours: " & iSpan.Hours & vbCrLf & " Minutes: " & iSpan.Minutes & vbCrLf & " Seconds: " & iSpan.Seconds & vbCrLf & "Initializing..."
                    Label8.Text = "Uptime - Hours: " & iSpan.Hours & " Minutes: " & iSpan.Minutes & " Seconds: " & iSpan.Seconds & "            Initializing..."
                    ret = "0.0"
                End If
                'Dim match As Match = regex.Match(lastline)
                newhashrate = Convert.ToDouble(ret)
            ElseIf line.Contains("NVIDIA") Then
                Dim regexnv As Regex = New Regex("\d{1,5}\.\d{1,1}") ' match a double
                Dim retnv = regexnv.Match(line).Value
                newNVhashRate = Convert.ToDouble(retnv)
                If firstNV = False Then
                    newser.Add(nvidiacard1)
                    nvidiacard1.Title = "NIVIDIA Hashrate(H/s)"
                    nvidiacard1.Values = nvidiavalues
                    For Each z In Chartvalues
                        Chartvalues.remove(z)
                    Next
                    nvidiavalues.add(0)
                    firstNV = True
                End If
            ElseIf line.Contains("AMD") Then
                Dim regexAMD As Regex = New Regex("\d{1,5}\.\d{1,1}") ' match a double
                Dim retAMD = regexAMD.Match(line).Value
                newAMDhashrate = Convert.ToDouble(retAMD)
                If firstAMD = False Then
                    newser.Add(AMDCard1)
                    AMDCard1.Title = "AMD Hashrate(H/s)"
                    AMDCard1.Values = AMDValues
                    For Each z In Chartvalues
                        Chartvalues.remove(z)
                    Next
                    AMDValues.add(0)
                    firstAMD = True
                End If
            End If
            ' Now if a GPU exists, add a new lineseries for CPU
            If firstAMD = True Or firstNV = True Then
                If firstCPU = False Then
                    newser.Add(CPU1)
                    CPU1.Title = "CPU Hashrate(H/s)"
                    CPU1.Values = CPUValues
                    For Each z In Chartvalues
                        Chartvalues.remove(z)
                    Next
                    CPUValues.add(0)
                    Chartvalues.add(0)
                    firstCPU = True
                End If
                newCPUhashrate = newhashrate - newNVhashRate - newAMDhashrate
            End If
        Next
    Catch
    End Try
    ' END NEW TEST
End Sub
```